# vbscript to display output upto the blank line

Tags: vbscript

My txt file1 is

```
Fruits
-------

Apple

Banana

Orange

Vegetables
---------
broccoli

Beans
```

txtfile 2

```
Fruits 

Vegetables
```

output should be:

```
Banana

Orange


Brocoli

Beans
```

I should be able to grab from ------- to blank space and I am having problems in doing that.

Comment: You must have tried something? Let's see your code.

Comment: Why would your output not include `Apple`?  Please look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)  to see how to ask and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for more info on providing examples

Answer (score 0):

I think the following code might give you some idea about reading txt files,

```
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
strWholeData = fso.OpenTextFile("C:\...\xxx.txt").ReadAll
strDataArr = Split(Trim(strWholeData),vbNewLine)
For di = Lbound(strDataArr) To Ubound(strDataArr)
    Msgbox strDataArr(di)
Next
```

Comment: Thank you Ismail so much. Appreciated .